# Stiffness of spring pendulum from position, velocity, and acceleration

Tags: mechanisms, stiffness

I'm working on a problem for which I have an external tool that integrates the equations of motion of a complex 'pendulum-like' mechanism (multiple beams, torsion springs and dampers, actuation, etc., see left side of image). Based only on the resulting **position**, **velocity**, and **acceleration** data of the mechanism, I would like to compute the stiffness (and damping) of the system as if it were replaced by a simple spring-mass model.

Now, for the sake of simplification, let's assume we do actually want to compute the stiffness of a 1D spring-mass model based on forward dynamic simulation resulting in position, velocity, and acceleration.

[image]

What I'm currently doing (for the 1D spring-mass model) is

- Simulate for $d_t$ and obtain $y$, $\dot{y}$, and $\ddot{y}$.
- Add a force $F$ to the bottom of the pendulum (this is also possible for the complex system!), simulate for $d_t$ and obtain $y_p$, $\dot{y}_p$, and $\ddot{y}_p$.
- Compute the stiffness as $K = \frac{F}{d_t \dot{y} - d_t \dot{y}_p}$ which is correct unit wise but this does not seem to make much sense.
- I try to use acceleration data and velocity data but at this point, I'm just trying things out instead of having a methodological approach.

I'm not 100% sure that this is even possible to do but let me know your insight.

Hopefully, I've made myself clear. What is the approach to get this 'representative stiffness' of a complex mechanism? Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Why get is $\delta_t$? Is it time?

Comment: A single spring-mass-damper has only one resonant mode. The complex system may have many resonant modes. So the single spring mass representation will necessarily be an approximation AFAIK.

Comment: @NMech, yes $\delta_t$ is the very short simulation time of the forward dynamics simulation

Comment: @AJN yes, but this is deliberate. I need an approximation of the stiffness as if it were a single spring-mass pendulum. This is from the fact that when you constrain the motion of the bottom of the complex system to lay on the line of the origin and its current location, you would feel a stiffness when perturbing the complex system

Comment: @J.V. Then its more common (in my experience) to use $dt$ as a symbol for timestep. As for the comment from AJN, I think what he is trying to say is that (even in the steady state) the response of a SDOF would be a (predictable) sinusoid, while in the case of an MDOF the steady state response almost looks chaotic.

Comment: Can you please mention the difference between $y$ and $y_p$ ? Is $y$ the physical parameter (position of some chosen point on the complex system and $y_p$ the position variable of the 1D pendulum ? I think equivalent stiffness can be derived based on infinitesimal movements $\Delta F / \Delta y$. But I don't know if that can be used for dynamic purposes. Are you familiar with the the concept of *generalized co-ordinates* and *modes of vibration* ? The fundamental mode of vibration may be a good choice for the equivalent single pendulum.

Comment: See one of my answers where an infinite degree of freedom system can be modeled as several single degree of freedom spring mass systems. The lowest frequency mode may be the 1D pendulum that you are looking for.

Comment: In order to to make sure that this is not a XY problem, consider telling us the final application of the 1D pendulum that you are going to derive for your complex system. Are you planning to use the final single pendulum spring stiffness for static or dynamic purposes. Depending on your need, the *correct* answer will vary.

Comment: @NMech You're correct, I've added in the $d_t$. See my reply to AJN for more clarity

Comment: @AJN Thanks for helping out so much. First off, I should have been more clear. Based on a force perturbation $F$, $y$ is the position of the 1D pendulum without the added force and $y_p$ is the 'perturbed' position of the 1D pendulum. I think I've also should have been more clear on the fact that I am assuming that the complex mechanism is to be replaced by a 1D pendulum. Basically, I am asking myself; what is the representative stiffness of a complex mechanism so that if we want to have it replaced by a 1D pendulum (in that specific condition/state) we just need to apply it with a stiffness.

Comment: @AJN The underlying goal is that via Computed Muscle Control I have a skeletal multibody system (with muscle activation) and I am looking at how the representative stiffness of the leg is changed throughout the human walking gait and under perturbations. The pendulum is then from the foot to the pelvis (or Center of Mass). It is a complex system but can be representated by a spring-mass model.

Comment: I think you shall familiarize yourself with finding the equivalent spring constant for "springs in series" and "springs in parallel".